# Nearest Points between two set of points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, time-complexity

There are two sets of points, said set A and B, and for each point a in set A, try to get a subset sub_B of B, that the distance between b in sub_B and a is smaller than the distance between b and any other A's point. And the point is 2-dimensional. For example, A = { (0,0), (3,0) }, B = { (1,1), (2,1) }, then for (0,0) in A, its set is {(1,1)}, for (3,0) in A, its set is {(2,1)}. Obviously, a brute force method could get the result in O(mn), where m is A's size and n is B's size. My question is whether there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the points in set A can be arranged into a [Space Paritioned Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) and every point in B can be used as query to find the nearest neighbor in set A and taking all the set of points with smallest distance. This gives a O(N*log(N)+M*log(N)) solution using kd-trees.